# Разбить строку с сохранением разделителя

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разбить строку с сохранением разделителя в Java?
Пример: Строка  +1 255 255  +3 100 100  +196 196

Нужно получить:
+1 255 255
+3 100 100
+196 196

```
split("\\b(?<=\\+)(?!$)")
```

Выдаёт:
+
1 255 255  +
3 100 100  +
196 196

Comment: Вам нужно это сделать имено в одно действие и именно `split`?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman   
Нет, не обязательно. Можно и matcher использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это решается простым [*положительным look-behind условием*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
 String str = "+1 255 255 +3 100 100 +196 196";
 String pattern = "(?=[+])";
 String[] items = str.split(pattern);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
```

> [+1 255 255 , +3 100 100 , +196 196]

Comment: Благодарю за ещё одно решение! Работает.

Comment: @spacenext пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать более простое выражение

```
final String regex = "\\+[^+]+";
final String string = "+1 255 255 +3 100 100 +196 196";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Для отладки регулярных выражений очень удобно использовать [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Благодарю!  То, что нужно.